# Video recorder app in Android using SurfaceView and media recorder: while recording video, it shows the 90 degree bend to left

Tags: android, video-recording

Video recording using SurfaceView, everything is fine, but the video is 90 degree left rotated while recording.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_capture);

SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
surfaceHolder = cameraView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Comment: please improve your question title making it shorter, but yet more direct. Also, please fix the indentation of the first line of source code in the question.

Comment: What device are you experiencing this on?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
camera.unlock();
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(2).toString());
mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
```